# Excel Queries and connection

Tags: excel, powerbi, data-modeling

Fairly new to power queries and finding my feet largely by trial and error.

I have an Excel file with two tables, “ModelName” is one
[image]

and “Vendors” is the other.

[image]

Table “ModelName” column “Model” contains unique values (one to one)

Table “Vendor” column “Model” contains the same names as the above table, but it has duplicate values (marked in red above) because I could potentially have the same Model containing a different Vendor or Controller (one to many).

I have created Queries & Connections and loaded/ added them to the Data Model.
I have also created a relationship between the two data models

[image]

But apparently, this isn’t working:

[image]

I was wondering if there is someone willing to point me in the right direction. What I am trying to do is to create one PivotTable from “ModelNames” which would contain “Model” and “12 Month Volume”. Then I would use all these slicers from “Vendor” and be able to filter the data from "Vendor" (which works fine) as well as the data/ Pivot Table from "ModelNames".
[image]

Comment: Have a look here: https://p3adaptive.com/2013/05/relationship-may-be-needed-but-i-already-have-a-relationship-whats-going-on/

Comment: Your screenshot of data  cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet.  To make the data useful please edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you @David. This definitely has helped and resolved my issue